# Setting the role for a calculated dimension (SSAS Cube)

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

The cube (sql Server 2016) contains dimensions `[Unit].[Unit].&[1]` and `[Unit].[Unit].&[2]`. I’ve created a calculated dimension:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Unit].[Unit].[All].[1/2] AS [Unit].[Unit].&[1]/[Unit].[Unit].&[2]
```

To restrict access to the dimension of `[Unit].[Unit].[All].[1/2]` I’ve created the Role.
But I can not select `[Unit].[Unit].[All].[1/2]`  in DimensionData-Basic tab, because this attribute does not appear in the list of attributes.
If I specify the attribute `[Unit].[Unit].[All].[1/2]`   in DimensionData-Advanced tab in the MDX-script `Denied member set: {[Unit].[Unit].[All].[1/2]}`, the user  sees this attribute.
How do I restrict access to the calculated dimension?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your DimUnit SQL table to include a "1/2" row then replace your `CREATE MEMBER` statement with the following it should work the same and you should be able to see this member in dimension data security after you deploy and process the cube:

```
([Unit].[Unit].[1/2]) 
     = DIVIDE([Unit].[Unit].&[1], [Unit].[Unit].&[2]);
```

Then after you have created a role that makes the 1/2 member disappear you will get an error when browsing the cube with that user. Change the above line to the following:

```
(IIf(IsError(StrToMember("[Unit].[Unit].[1/2]",CONSTRAINED)),Head([Unit].[Unit].Members,0),StrToMember("[Unit].[Unit].[1/2]",CONSTRAINED))
    = DIVIDE([Unit].[Unit].&[1], [Unit].[Unit].&[2]);
```

BTW, `DIVIDE` does safe divide so divide by zero won't cause problems.

Off the top of my head I can't recall if StrToMember is necessary vs. just a member reference so I played it safe. Feel free to try it without StrToMember.

To be clear the whole script should say:

```
CALCULATE;

(IIf(IsError(StrToMember("[Unit].[Unit].[1/2]",CONSTRAINED)),Head([Unit].[Unit].Members,0),StrToMember("[Unit].[Unit].[1/2]",CONSTRAINED))
    = DIVIDE([Unit].[Unit].&[1], [Unit].[Unit].&[2]);
```

Comment: I replaced old “create member” and I’ve error when browsing the cube with that user.
I do not understand where I should insert

`(IIf(IsError(StrToMember("[Unit].[Unit].[1/2]",CONSTRAINED)),Head([Unit].[Unit].Members,0),StrToMember("[Unit].[Unit].[1/2]",CONSTRAINED)) = DIVIDE([Unit].[Unit].&[1], [Unit].[Unit].&[2])`

In the «Calculation» in a cube or in DimensionData-Advanced tab in the role (“Denied member set”)?

Comment: Go to the Calculations tab and flip to the script view. That statement goes there after `CALCULATE`

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I'm writing a script:
`CALCULATE; 
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Unit].[Unit].[1/2] AS 
(IIF(IsError(StrToMember('[Unit].[Unit].[1/2]', CONSTRAINED)),
HEAD([Unit].[Unit].Members,0),
StrToMember('[Unit].[Unit].[1/2]', CONSTRAINED)) =
DIVIDE([Unit].[Unit].&[1], [Unit].[Unit].&[2]));`
But i get an error "the object was not found in the cube when the string [Unit].[Unit].&[1/2] was parsed".

Comment: @Natalya after you add the extra row to the dimension table and reprocess the dimension the change the script. I edited my answer to make it clearer. You don't need `CREATE MEMBER`